# Linear algebra, det, isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inner-products, isometry

> Prove or disprove:
>
> $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ , $T$ is an isometry, and  $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$, then $|$det$T$|$=1$.

My answer to this is the statement is right, since if $T$ is an isometry then $T^{-1}$=$T^*$, but the problem is I have some intuition in my mind, but I don't know how to write down the proof. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is an isometry then $T^*T=I$, and also $T^*=T^t$ since $V$ is real. Therefore
$$ 1=\det(T^tT)=\det(T^t)\det(T)=\det(T)^2 $$
so $\det(T)=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $T B(0,1) = B(0,1)$ hence the change of variables theorem gives:
$\int_{B(0,1)} 1 dx = \int_{B(0,1)} 1 |\det T| dx$, from which we get
$|\det T| = 1$.