# Prove that $\det R = \pm 1$ iff $R \in \mathrm{Isom}(V)$, without using $\det R = \det R^T$

Tags: determinant, inner-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, isometry

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real inner product space. An isometry on $V$ is an operator $R$ with $\langle Rx,Ry \rangle$ for all $x,y \in V$. The determinant of an Endomorphism can be defined in many ways. One of them is as follows. Since the the space $\Lambda^n V$ is $1$-dimensional then for any basis $\{v_j\}$ we have
$$
Rv_1\wedge\dots\wedge Rv_n = (\det R)\ v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n,
$$
where $\det R$ is the proportionality factor. Now to show from these definitions that for an isometry $R$ we have $\det R= \pm 1$, I define the inner product on $\Lambda^n V$ such that
$$
\langle u_1\wedge\dots\wedge u_n,v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n \rangle
:= \det \langle u_i, v_j \rangle
= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\pi)
\langle u_1,v_{\pi 1} \rangle \cdots \langle u_n,v_{\pi n} \rangle,
$$
and show that
$$
\|Rv_1\wedge\dots\wedge Rv_n\| = \| v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_n \|
$$
and hence $|\det R| = 1$. But this might be an exotic way, since it involves a new space with an inner product, but I'm very sure why it works.

Is there another way without any standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ or any matrices ? In the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884872/linear-algebra-det-isometry) it relies on the fact $\det R = \det R^T$, where $R^T$ is the adjoint of $R$, but that is not proved in that answer, clearly it is a matrix trick.

By the way one can define $\det R$ as proportionality factor of elements of $\Lambda^n V^*$ as
$$
\omega(Rv_1,\dots,Rv_n) = \det R\ \omega(v_1,\dots,v_n)
$$
but I couldn't continue from there.

Comment: In your last line, you need to be careful about the difference between ${\bigwedge}V^*$ and $({\bigwedge}V)^*$. What you really mean here is the latter, and the ability to identify the two of them comes precisely from a form between ${\bigwedge}V^*$ and ${\bigwedge}V$ like your inner product, so this approach does not avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

$
\require{AMScd}
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\MVects[1]{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge^{\!#1}}}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\End{\mathrm{End}}
$Your inner product on $\Ext V$ as written is ill-defined
because the $n$-fold wedge product on the LHS
is antisymmetric in the vectors $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$
and the vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ but your RHS is not.
It should instead be
$$
  \form{u_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge u_n,\; v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n}
    = \sum_{\pi\in S_n}\color{red}{\mathrm{sgn}(\pi)}\form{u_1, v_{\pi(1)}}\dotsc\form{u_n, v_{\pi(n)}}
    = \det\Bigl(\form{u_i, v_j}\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^n
$$

There is not any way to get around using the inner product on $\Ext V$
in some form or another.
(Though it's hidden, this is also true of the Clifford algebra approach
I mentioned.)

However, I realized we don't even need to invoke the Clifford algebra;
the idea of that proof is actually quite simple.
Choose $I \in \MVects nV$ so that $\form{I, I} \ne 0$;
because $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ is an inner product,
any non-zero $I$ will suffice.
Now observe that $\form{R(I), R(I)} = \form{I, I}$ by definition of $R$
and by examining the definition of $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$.
Now we see immediately:
$$
  (\det R)^2\form{I, I} = \form{R(I), R(I)} = \form{I, I}
  \implies
  (\det R)^2 = 1
$$
and so of course $\det R = \pm1$.

---

By $R(I)$ what I mean is the *outermorphism* of $R$ applied to $I$;
less ambiguous notation would perhaps be $\Ext R(I)$.
This is defined such that if $I = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n$ then
$$
  \Ext R(I) = R(v_1)\wedge\dotsb\wedge R(v_n)$.
$$
It's not essential to the above proof, but we can show that $\Ext R$
is a well-defined linear function $\Ext V \to \Ext V$.

However, it *is* essential to showing that $\det R = \det R^T$.
I will just give the major points without going into detail.

First, extend the natural pairing $\form{\cdot,\cdot} : V^* \times V \to \R$
to a pairing $\Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \R$
in the same way that we extended the inner product $V\times V \to \R$
to an inner product $\Ext V\times \Ext V \to \R$.
This gives us an isomorphism $\psi : \Ext V^* \to (\Ext V)^*$.
Similarly we consider the isomorphism $\flat : V \to V^*$
given by the inner product, often written $v \mapsto v^\flat$
with the inverse denoted by $\sharp$.
this extends uniquely to an isomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V^*$
which we will also denote by $\flat$ and the inverse by $\sharp$.
Note that $R^T = \sharp\circ R^*\circ\flat$.

Second, show that taking outermorphisms
commutes with taking duals under this isomorphism;
i.e. the following diagram commutes for all $R : V \to V$:
$$\begin{CD}
  \Ext V^*       @>{\psi}>> (\Ext V)^* \\
  @V{\Ext R^*}VV            @VV{(\Ext R)^*}V \\
  \Ext V^*       @>{\psi}>> (\Ext V)^*
\end{CD}$$
or in function notation $\psi\circ\Ext R^* = (\Ext R)^*\circ\psi$.
(In categorical language, $\psi$ is a natural isomorphism of functors
${\Ext}\circ{*} \cong {*}\circ{\Ext}$.)

Third, prove that for any isomorphism $\phi : V \to W$ that $\det
(\phi^{-1}\circ R\circ \phi) = \det R$.

Finally, choose $I \in \MVects nV$ and $\omega \in \MVects nV^*$
such that $\form{\omega, I} \ne 0$.
It follows by applying $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$, the definiton of determinant,
and the above that
$$
  \det R = \det R^* = \det(\flat\circ R^T\circ\sharp) = \det R^T.
$$